# yii2 Url Manager, get параметр

Tags: php, yii2

Можно ли с помощью Url-manager, скрыть get параметр? 
Использую `SluggableBehavior`
Сейчас поисковый запрос выдает вот такой

`http://standart.dev/complex-slug?slug=zk-novyj-kvartal&price=100`

Можно ли сделать его вот таким - 
`complex/search?zk-novyj-kvartal&price=100&...` ? Или лучше вот такой `complex/zk-novyj-kvartal/search?price=100&`
Тоесть нужно скрыть первый параметр..

Таким образом пробывал прописать в правилах - но не работает - Unable to resolve the request

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [ ...
                'complex/<slug>/search' => 'site/complex-slug?slug=<slug>',
                ....
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй таким образом

```
'rules' => [ ...
    'complex/<slug:[\w-]+>/search' => 'site/complex-slug',
    ....
],
```